# Apktool Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Animation.OptionsPanel'

Tags: android, android-security

I was trying to rebuild an apk using apktool (apktool-2.1.1).

Encountered an error

i) No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Animation.OptionsPanel'

ii)No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Animation.LockScreen'

Error Msg:

```
I: Using Apktool 2.1.1
I: Copying /home/workspace/debug/app-demo-release classes.dex file...
I: Building resources...
W: /home/workspace/debug/app-demo-release/res/values-v24/styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Animation.OptionsPanel'.
W: 
W: /home/workspace/debug/app-demo-release/res/values-v24/styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Animation.LockScreen'.
W: 
Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 1): [/tmp/brut_util_Jar_1478810839657812213.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 15, --target-sdk-version, 22, --version-code, 6, --version-name, 1.0.5-debug, -F, /tmp/APKTOOL7363633357993529625.tmp, -0, arsc, -0, woff2, -0, assets/io/michaelrocks/libphonenumber/android/data/PhoneNumberAlternateFormatsProto_66, -0, arsc, -I, /home/workspace/debug/apktool/framework/1.apk, -S, /home/workspace/debug/app-demo-release/res, -M, /home/workspace/debug/app-demo-release/AndroidManifest.xml]
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResourcesFull(Androlib.java:437)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResources(Androlib.java:371)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:281)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:254)
    at brut.apktool.Main.cmdBuild(Main.java:224)
    at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:84)
```

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Info.Media" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Info" />
        <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Media" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification" />
        <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Time.Media" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Time" />
        <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Title.Media" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Title" />
        <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored" parent="@android:style/Animation.OptionsPanel" />
        <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Colored" parent="@android:style/Animation.LockScreen" />
    </resources>
```

Answer (score 5):

remove ~/Library/apktool/ folder(Mac OS)，and re-run apktool, everything will be OK.

Comment: I am used -p ./apktool/framework/ and ever time remove /apktoo/l folder......


java -jar ./apktool_2.3.3.jar d -p ./apktool/framework/ -f ./app-demo-release.apk -o ./app-demo-release/

java -jar ./apktool_2.3.3.jar b -p ./apktool/framework/ -f ./app-demo-release/ -o ./app-demo-release.apk

Answer (score 2):

Based on Daniel Wang's answer, `apktool`'s copy of the frameworks might be out of date, and removing it will re-create it with a newer SDK version at next run. The [apktool documentation](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/documentation/) lists the locations, and since version 2.2.1 it also provides a new command for those:

```
apktool empty-framework-dir
```

Quoting the [relevant documentation](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/documentation/) below:

---

Apktool has no knowledge of what version of framework resides there. It will assume its up to date, so delete the file during Apktool upgrades

### Managing framework files

Frameworks are stored in different places depending on the OS in question.

- unix - `$HOME/.local/share/apktool`
- windows - `%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\apktool`
- mac - `$HOME/Library/apktool`

If these directories are not available it will default to `java.io.tmpdir` which is usually `/tmp`. This is a volatile directory so it would make sense to take advantage of the parameter `--frame-path` to select an alternative folder for framework files.

Since these locations are in sometimes hidden directories, managing these frameworks becomes a challenge. A simple helper function (added in v2.2.1) allows you to run `apktool empty-framework-dir` to empty out frameworks.

Note Apktool has no control over the frameworks once installed, but you are free to manage these files on your own.

Comment: I am used -p ./apktool/framework/ and ever time remove /apktoo/l folder...... java -jar ./apktool_2.3.3.jar d -p ./apktool/framework/ -f ./app-demo-release.apk -o ./app-demo-release/ java -jar ./apktool_2.3.3.jar b -p ./apktool/framework/ -f ./app-demo-release/ -o ./app-demo-release.apk

Answer (score 0):

you can delete this lines
it is builder added lines from sources

in Android Studio lines line a `"<style name="Base...."` drawing with yellow color - it is ovverides